# Cypress Login With Redirect

Tags: cypress, session-cookies, cypress-login

I would like to create Cypress script that does the following:

1. Logs into the platform
2. Stores the session for the following tests - so I do not have to log in each time it executes a new test
3. Executes the rest of the tests

**1. WORKING, but not ideal**

I did manage to make it work when I start the script by visiting

```
cy.visit('https://localhost:3000/login')
```

but then I have two problems:

**A. Rest of the code needs to be in the origin function:**

```
cy.origin('https://localhost:3000/login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')
    // test script
})
```

**B. More important:**

- It does not keep the session
- After several logins the user somehow stops working and is no longer authenticated by the platform.

**2. NOT WORKING, ideal**

So I wanted to start the script the proper way by visiting

```
cy.visit('https://localhost:3000/')
```

then clicking on the `Log In` button

```
cy.contains('Log In')
    .click()
```

and here is the tricky part - Once the user clicks to the `Log In` button the URL is `https://localhost:3000/login` (Status Code **302**) redirects the user to

```
https://staging.XXX.com/login?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Freturn_from_login&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=%7B%22full%22%3A+true%7D
```

and once I am making the script working that way I have two problems:

a. Chrome asks me to allow redirect

b. Once allowed, I am redirected outside of the Cypress so the left sidebar disappears completely

[image: Cypress sidebar is gone]

Does anybody know how to solve this?

The whole code is

```
describe('User Session + Start a Discussion', () => {
    const username = "username";
    const password = "password";

    before(() => {
        cy.session("User Session", () => {

            cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')

            cy.contains('Log In')
                .click()
            
            cy.contains('Allow All Cookies', { timeout: 60000 })
                .should('be.visible')

            cy.contains('Allow All Cookies')
                .click()

            cy.get('input[placeholder="Username or Email"]')
                .type(username)
        
            cy.contains('Next')
                .click()
            
            cy.get('input[placeholder="Password"]')
                .type(password)
            
            cy.contains('Log In')
                .click()

            cy.get('button[data-bind="html: actionButtonHTML, click: consentToGrantAction, disable: busy"]', { timeout: 120000 })
                .should('be.visible')

            cy.get('button[data-bind="html: actionButtonHTML, click: consentToGrantAction, disable: busy"]')
                .click()
        })
    })


    it('Starts a new Discussion', () => {
        cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')
        
        cy.get('a[href="/discussions"]', { timeout: 120000 }).should('be.visible')

        cy.get('a[href="/discussions"]')
            .click()

        cy.contains('Start a discussion', { timeout: 20000})
            .click()

        cy.contains('Attach to Discussion...')
            .click()

        cy.get('#object-selector-modal-1').should('be.visible')

        cy.get('[data-classname="file"]')
            .click()

        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .media > .media-body > label > input')
            .click()            

        cy.get('[data-bind="click: save, css: {disabled: !canSave()}, disable: !canSave()"]')
            .click()

        cy.get('textarea[class="ace_text-input"]')
            .type("New Discussion", {force: true})

        cy.contains('Publish')
            .click({force: true})

        cy.contains('Publish selected objects')
            .click({force: true})
    })

})
```

I tried to check Gleb's youtube [vids](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mML36U62-fQ) and also Cypress [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Stubbing-and-spying) but I did not manage to make it work :-(

I was also trying to create as a smaller parts of the code like

```
it('Homepage', () => {
    cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')
})


it('Login', () => { 
    cy.visit('https://localhost:3000/login')
    // Login code
})

it('Test', () => {  
    // Do sth once logged in
})
```

But I was not authorized as the user when I tried that this way..

I have this in my **cypress.config.js** file:

`"experimentalSessionAndOrigin": true`

**Any ideas, tips on how to solve it? Big thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is pretty close, here's what I think you need to change.

**Avoiding frame-busting**

You should be able to avoid the redirect jumping out of the Cypress runner by visiting it directly inside the `cy.session()`.

**Calling pattern for cy.session()**

`cy.session()` should be in a `beforeEach()` not a `before()`.  It's purpose is to reinstate the auth cookies for each `it()`, so it must be called before each test.

**Visit main URL at the top of each test**

`cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')` is required for every test, see [session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)

> Because the page is cleared at the beginning of each test, cy.visit() must be explicitly called at the beginning of each test.

**Origin command isn't required**

`cy.origin()` is not required when the two origins are in different execution blocks, i.e `https://staging.XXX.com/login` in the `beforeEach()` and `https://localhost:3000` in the `it()` block.

---

Here is the general pattern, I've left out some lines for clarity

```js
describe('User Session + Start a Discussion', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.session("User Session", () => {
            cy.visit('https://staging.XXX.com/login')
            cy.contains('Log In').click()
            ...          
            cy.get('input[placeholder="Username or Email"]').type(username)
            cy.contains('Next').click()
            cy.get('input[placeholder="Password"]').type(password)
            cy.contains('Log In').click()
            ...
        })
    })

    it('Starts a new Discussion', () => {
        cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')       //  logged-in state
        ...
    })

    it('Further test', () => {
        cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')       //  logged-in state
        ...
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi @Fody, thank you very much for your response, can I kindly ask you to check my answer and I could not post it as a comment here? Thank you! :-)